# webGL and iOS Build Support Install failed -Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, build, download, webgl

I don't know why I am getting this error. how can i solve this ?
(Visual studio 2019 was already installed but I never had access to the others)

[image: Unity hub downloads error image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens... Moreover, it may not be possible to reinstall the module, since it is already marked as installed. In this case, you can do the following:

1. Find the folder where Unity is installed. For example: `C:\Program Files\UnityEditor\2021.2.13f1`
2. Open the `modules.json` file
3. Find the object with the parameter `"name":"iOS Build Support"` and in this object change the parameter `"selected":true` to `"selected":false`
4. Restart Unity Hub and try to reinstall iOS Build Support module

Also make sure you have enough disk space to install the components